# Where do you put your template override files?

Tags: theming, commerce

I am trying to get Drupal to recognize a template override that is a theme hook suggestion.
However, I don't know how to get Drupal 7 to recognize it.

Specifically, Drupal commerce allows for the override of a customer order using the template file
commerce-order--commerce-order--customer.tpl.php

I don't know where to put this.

I tried putting the file in my own theme directory, and clearing the cache. But it didn't recognize it.  Do I need to add something to the .info file of my theme?

I DID GET THIS TO WORK when I put the template in the main theme of the site, namely the omega_kickstart template directory. But this is not ideal for upgrading.

Finally, I tried making my theme a sub theme of omega_kickstart thinking it would override then, but that didn't work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this the only tpl file that your template isn't loading?

Answer (score 0):

When creating new templates for your theme you need to name it to match your theme.

You'll want something like:

```
YOURTHEMENAME--commerce-order--customer.tpl.php
```

Comment: I am overriding the entity commerce-order and using the theme_hook_suggestions for commerce entities from commerce module. I am pretty sure this is the correct naming convention because it works in the omega_kickstart theme. I did try what you suggested though, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly this file is going to override? if it is a node then use this code in `template.php`

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['node']->type == 'SomeThing') {
    // This will look for template named page--commerce.tpl.php in your theme.
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__commerce';
    }
}
```

then create file `page--commerce.tpl.php` in your theme directory

and if it is a view you can do the same in `hook_preprocess_views_view` or there is another solution in [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86630/is-it-possible-to-have-one-views-view-viewname-page-tpl-for-multiple-views)

Comment: What I am overriding is a commerce_order entity.  I am using the theme_hook_suggestions that are defined by commerce already so I don't think I need to define my own.  When I turn on theme debug, commerce-order--commerce-order--customer.tpl.php is one of the suggestions for overriding the page.  As I said, it works in the default theme, just not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file in your theme directory, you need to clear the theme-registry cache to get the new template to register.

If you have drush: `drush cc theme-registry`

If you do not, use the Clear Cache button (Admin >> Configuration >> Development >> Performance) a few times. You should then have your new template registered.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache using drush, and it still doesn't show up. Thank you though for making me aware of how to clear the cache using drush. That will be useful in the future