# page.tpl.php base on a field criteria in views

Tags: views, theming

I'm working on creating different themes in different pages of a site base on several conditions.

first, I want to create a page.tpl.php for all view pages in my site.

second, I want to have tiny specialization on it base on the filter criteria field's value or selected field's value in a page view. I mean different page.tpl.php based on fields value criteria.

I need to change the overall theme so it is not duplicate of [is it possible to have one views-view--VIEWNAME--page.tpl for multiple views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86630/is-it-possible-to-have-one-views-view-viewname-page-tpl-for-multiple-views)

I need to know how to access field's value in my "function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) ".

Comment: Read https://www.drupal.org/node/173880

Answer (score 0):

Salam,
You can do this using `hook_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)`. Your code should be like this:

```
function YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
    $view = $vars['view'];
    // the values of the view, filter criteria and the value of fields are in $view
    if(CONDITION1 == true)   
        $vars['theme_suggestion'] = 'views_view__custom_pages1'
    else if(CONDITION2 == true)   
        $vars['theme_suggestion'] = 'views_view__custom_pages2'
}
```

Then create files `views_view__custom_pages1.tpl.php` and `views_view__custom_pages2.tpl.php` and theme the view. In this way different themes are defined for the same view.

You also said *I need to know how to access field's value in my "function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) "*, what variables do you need to find it's value?

Comment: salam! :) does it override page.tpl.php or just the the area of the view? About fields' value I need to have different overridden page.tpl.php depend on the taxonomy ID in my Contextual filter.

Comment: it effects the view's context. If you need to change the entire `page.tpl.php` use the above code in `hook_preprocess_page` and check for the value of the view.

The above function is called before the `hook_preprocess_page` so you can set a static variable which it's value is the value of the view then use that variable in the `hook_preprocess_page`.

Comment: I try it but doesn't work. I do this in another way for now. thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: You can also use context module

Comment: that's right but I don't like module base approaches. thanks