# Implement multiple views-blocks in a custom template page

Tags: views, blocks

I have 3 views-blocks and these blocks should be available with a single url only. Just say `example.com/personal-content` .

I want to place this blocks in this single URL based on  a custom design.
Like one in the first side bar, another in the second side bar and the third one in the top .

How do I proceed to implement the same.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can achieve this by following [solution][1] 


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86630/is-it-possible-to-have-one-views-view-viewname-page-tpl-for-multiple-views

Comment: @rfegade , Thanks, but that solution is for  multiple views use one template. But my case is I've 3 blocks and I want insert all into a same template page.

Comment: I'm sorry but can please you give some examples or a more detailed explanation of the scenario you want to solve?

Comment: DareScorp, how is what you are asking different than what you can achieve by positioning the blocks via the Blocks administration interface?

Comment: @othermachines , yeah.. there is a way  using admin side interface. But the three blocks fetch the data from three content types. And i know only defining template for a single content type.  Is it possible to define a single template for a particular url ?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you mean. That the blocks are dynamically generated by Views - or how they are generated - should not affect how you can position them. Blocks are blocks. :) If you want to limit their visibility to that URL, just set that up in the block configuration.